# Multiple Checkbox selection and parsing data into json in android? How can i write code?

Tags: android

I am new android developer in my company. I maintain a project.. In my project, 3 checkboxes are there and when we click on those checkboxes, it can be selectable mutiple and if we click button those values are stored into json in android. How can i write code? anybody give me advice.. I will send my layout design just for idea purpose you..

[ChefRegistration design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K42E5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the code below,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private CheckBox cbDineIn;
private CheckBox cbTakeOut;
private CheckBox cbDelivery;

private Button btnDone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initUI();
}

private void initUI(){

    cbDineIn =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbDineInActivityMain);
    cbTakeOut =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbtakeOutActivityMain);
    cbDelivery =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbDeliveryActivityMain);
    btnDone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDoneActivityMain);

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private JSONObject generateJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObjectChoices = new JSONObject();
    try {
        if(cbDineIn.isChecked()){
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Dine-In","YES");
        }else {
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Dine-In","NO");
        }
        if(cbTakeOut.isChecked()){
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Take-Out","YES");
        }else {
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Take-Out","NO");
        }
        if(cbDelivery.isChecked()){
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Delivery","YES");
        }else {
            jsonObjectChoices.put("Delivery","NO");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObjectChoices;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    generateJSON();
}
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem please do mark it as an answer so it would be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Better you can set unique tag or id to your each CheckBoxes and then you can get the id or tag when you click the button.

Set those values in JSON and send.

To understand about JSON, you have lot of opportunities.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial

Comment: Hai sridhar. I am already set uniwue id for each check boxes and get id.. but I dont know json parsing have you any code in your previous project.. please post your code i'll observe and do it..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough

In android, if you need to generate JSON

try this one

```
CheckBox checkBox;

checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@override
public void onClick(){
String jsonObject = generateJSONData();
Log.i("Json Data", jsonObject);
}

}

public String generateJSONData(){
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("name","ajay");
    jsonObj.put("address","fairfield");

    return jsonObj.toString();
    }
}
```

This code will generate JSON on CheckBox click.

The output will be

{
name:"ajay",
address:"fairfield"
}

I just write this code. I didn't test it. Hope it helps you :)